# Align forms under each other HTML/CSS

Tags: php, html, css, forms, alignment

For school I am making a little website for kids to learn calculating. I made php create 10 random sums and placed them in seperate divisions under each other. Each division contains a form. But because the text (sums) are all different lengths these forms won't align directly under each other.

this is the script that creates the sums:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Rekenen</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Delen - Toets</h2>
<div class="textboxlarge">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php?pagina=28">
<?php session_start();

for($teller=1;$teller<11;$teller++){

$numberone = rand(5, 150); 
$numbertwo = rand(5, 150);
$getal1[$teller]=$numberone;
$getal2[$teller]=$numbertwo;
$_SESSION['getal1']=$getal1;
$_SESSION['getal2']=$getal2;  

echo "<div class='som'>$numberone : $numbertwo = <input name='$teller' ></div><br>";

}
  ?> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="verzenden">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On the website it will look like this:
http://gyazo.com/52686785c5beb0e1e97f8b8682c200fb

Now my qeustion is, What is the best way to align the blank forms?
(Sorry for my bad english, I am not a native English speaker but I did my best.)

Comment: please provide a valid link to the screen

Comment: Thankyou for the heads up, It should work now

Comment: Your example link doesn’t work; and the script you have shown does not create 10 separate _forms_, but one form with several `div` with input fields. As for aligning, place the numbers in separate HTML elements, and make those have a width that is enough to hold the largest numbers. floating or `display:inline-block` might be required to achieve that. If those techniques don’t mean anything to you yet, then please go and work through some tutorials on the basics of layouting with CSS first.

Comment: I fixed this link, And I think I can do it with what you told me. I will tell you if it worked ! Thanks already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why wouldnt you use tables?

Something like this:

```
<table>

<?php session_start();

for($teller=1;$teller<11;$teller++){

$numberone = rand(5, 150); 
$numbertwo = rand(5, 150);
$getal1[$teller]=$numberone;
$getal2[$teller]=$numbertwo;
$_SESSION['getal1']=$getal1;
$_SESSION['getal2']=$getal2;  

echo "<tr class='som'><td>$numberone : $numbertwo =</td><td> <input name='$teller'></td></tr>";

}
?> 
</table>
```

You probably have to change the css a little to achieve the same look.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of your numbers, apply `span`s for the numbers within your div and style them like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/7YF5q/